# Why is my recursive function seems to run only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

This is the code, it goes over an object looking for deeply-nested children and supposed to stop once there are no more children or it exceeds ALLOWED_NESTING_DEPTH.

The `console.log` seems to run only once, although I do get the correct number.

```js
const ALLOWED_NESTING_DEPTH = 4

function traverseChildren (childrenIdList, parentsNesting = 0) {
  parentsNesting++

  if (parentsNesting > ALLOWED_NESTING_DEPTH || _.isEmpty(childrenIdList)) {
    console.log(parentsNesting) // Why does this show only once even if there are many levels of nesting?
    return parentsNesting
  }


  let children = childrenIdList.map(child => _.find(tree.items, { id: child }))
  let allChildren = []
  if (!_.isEmpty(children)) {
    allChildren = _.flattenDeep(children.map(child => child.children))
  }

  return traverseChildren(allChildren, parentsNesting)
}

traverseChildren(someChild)
```

Comment: `childrenIdList` is only empty once?  A simple console log of each conditional of the if would tell you why it's false.  Or throw a `debugger;` in there and look at things

Comment: Because you're doing the `console.log` only in your base case, not on every single function call?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the `flattenDeep`

Comment: What is `someChild`?  Can you expand this into a [mre]?

Comment: FYI: This is strictly speaking _tail recursion_ only.  Because the only place that `traverseChildren` calls `traverseChildren` is at the very end of the function.  Which means you could have written it as a loop. Do this by enclosing the whole thing in a `while(true)` block and then putting `childrenIdList = allChildren` instead of the call to `traverseChildren` .

Answer (score 3):

When you enter this block:

```
if (parentsNesting > ALLOWED_NESTING_DEPTH || _.isEmpty(childrenIdList)) {
    console.log(parentsNesting) // Why does this show only once even if there are many levels of nesting?
    return parentsNesting
  }
```

... you are returning an object and not calling the function again. In other words, this is your terminating case. You only come through here once, so you only see one `console.log`.